# How to upload a corrected CD tracklist to the Windows Media Player database?

Tags: windows-media-player

Using Windows Media Player 11.

I have a number of CDs for which the tracklist WMP has downloaded is incorrect.  In one or two cases, the identity of the album (or single) isn't even correct.

I can edit the title and artist of the CD and each track within WMP.  But how would I go about submitting the corrected information to the global WMP database, so that other users may benefit?

Comment: Nope, there is not any "global WMP database", the infos about artists / covers / etc comes from different repositories and are "read-only", imagine a HTTP GET for simplicity

Comment: But surely the people who maintain these repositories can correct the information in them?

Comment: Part of the problem is that some labels re-use serial numbers for completely different albums, so the database can never be correct.  I've disabled the option to download metadata and enter everything in manually.

Answer (score 0):

One of the databases that is used by WMP is AMG's ([All Music Guide](http://www.allmusic.com/)) database.

As for submitting corrections, see the 5th question under CD Playback at http://zachd.com/pss/pss.html#CD : `WMP is showing the wrong content information about my CD. How do I fix this?`, although I don't know if this information is still correct.